# How are PCI lanes used for graphics and peripherals (eg PCI-e SSD) respectively?

Tags: graphics-card, ssd, cpu, motherboard

The [Skylake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_%28microarchitecture%29) architecture supports 16 PCI-E lanes from the CPU and 20 from the [PCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub).

Are the 20 from the Z170 chipset separate from the 16 that allow the CPU to communicate with the GPU(s)?  Or is the 16 a subset of the 20?

Comment: Those voting to close, I'd appreciate an explanation of why it's such a poor question.  I'm more than happy to improve it, but I don't find the articles I've already read all that clear.  Downvotes with no comment are lazy.

Comment: I didn't vote to close (yet), but your question has several problems.  Asking for hardware recommendations (helping you make purchase decisions), is off-topic.  Asking whether some potential hardware will be adequate for nebulous future hardware is also opinion-based, which is off-topic.  A technical question like your last paragraph is on-topic unless a proper answer would take volumes of explanation.  Suggestion: reword your question to focus on a specific technical issue that has the kind of answer that could be looked up in a reference source (like the last paragraph).

Comment: The issue here is that this is primarily a hardware recommendation question, as it discusses whether a specific hardware item meets a set of requirements. Instead, as @fixer1234 noted, try to focus on a particular technical issue that can be specifically addressed.

Comment: I've tried a different form of the question following the comments.  More than happy to edit again if necessary.  Thanks for the explanations @fixer1234 and DragonLord.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand (your general question) you want to make sure if you can connect PCIE3 x16 GPU and other devices to motherboard, right? (Sorry but it's a little bit unclear what you want to achieve.)

AFAIK CPUs usually have separate lanes for GPU (for PCIE slots) though they can communicate to other onboard devices (such as onboard HD audio, USB 3, etc) with PCIE lanes too.
Search for "Intel ARK " and find there `PCI Express Configurations`. If it says something like `up to 1x16, 2x8, 1x8 & 2x4` then you have 16 free lanes for PCIE slot (for GPU).

But usually lanes are managed by motherboard.
So look at your chipset PCIE configurations carefully, for example Z170 from [Gigabyte](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5499#sp) and [Asus](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-DELUXE/specifications/).
Both motherboards support PCIE x16 or 2x8 (shared) at PCIE3 speeds, also have shared x4 lanes.
So you can use x16 lanes for GPU (at PCIE3 speed), also you can connect for example an SSD but at x4 speed. (P.S. If I'm incorrect or said something wrong, tell me.)

Other articles for more info about PCI Express:
[How can mainboards provide more PCIe lanes than the chipset?](https://superuser.com/q/838092/180465)
[PCI express basics](http://www.enthusiastpc.net/articles/00003/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good resource for understanding how the PCI lanes are managed. Bottom line: Yes, you have only 16 lanes directly to the CPU from the GPU, but you have an additional 20 lanes that can be used through the motherboard chip set (and DMI 3.0 interface).
https://www.hardocp.com/article/2015/08/12/intel_z170_chipset_summary
Some newer Motherboards have two x16 PCI slots, but you won't get two GPUs in SLI (or crossfire) to run x16/x16 they will default to x8/x8 (though you won't notice any real difference) because the CPU PCI lanes only total 16 (not 32). The other x16 slot could be used for some new product that runs x16 (none that I know of) or a second GPU card that runs at different times from your main GPU but you don't want to have to uninstall them. Another reason would be to use an SSD that can take advantage of the higher than 4GB/s maximum that the Platform Control Hub (PCH) is limited to by the DMI 3.0 interface, but then you would be limiting your GPU to just x8 to use either x8 or x4/x4 for the SSD. The other 20 PCI lanes run through the PCH controller and would be limited by the DMI 3.0 interface to a maximum of 4GB/s which is not a big deal because they are all PCIe 3.0 x4 lanes, unless you are trying to run a RAID 0 set of M.2 PCIe NVMe SSDs which would then be topped out byt he DMI 3.0 interface to no more than 4GB/s.