# Asus Z170-A M.2 SSD and PCIe - Can I run more than one in RAID?

Tags: ssd, raid, pci-express, m2-connector

I have an Asus Z170-A that's now a few years old. When I bought it I could only afford conventional 250GB SATA SSD and 1TB HDD combination. My Steam games are on the HDD.

With prices falling I would like to upgrade storage to move my games on to some combination of SSDs. I could easily add a single M.2 SSD, but I also started to look at the possibility of a RAID 0 configuration making use of the dedicated M.2 and also a vacant PCIe slot.

I'm confused about PCIe lanes and if my board will support two new SSDs in this configuration? I have a GTX 1070 at 16x, and from what I can see the Z170-A has 16+4 lanes. If I try to run an M.2 at 4x and another in a PCIe slot at 4x, will I be over what's possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can mainboards provide more PCIe lanes than the chipset?](https://superuser.com/questions/838092/how-can-mainboards-provide-more-pcie-lanes-than-the-chipset)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that other question - my question is specifically about the Z170-A board. Please remove tag?